# Why does Latin show some adverbs as conjunctions?

Tags: grammar-choice

Some words in Latin are shown as being adverbs, yet they have the meaning of conjunctions, at least I guess. The word "quapropter" can be an example. I don't know if I'm mistaken, but I find that weird.

Comment: Where are they shown as being adverbs, and why do you think they should be conjunctions? More detail will help you get a useful answer.

Comment: The dictionaries I use. Lewis and Short, some latin-portuguese dictionaries. I don't know if they should. Their translations from Latin show the meanings of conjuctions in Portuguese.  Quapropter in Portuguese, sometimes has the meaning of "therefore".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't so complicated, and it's not limited to Latin. The same is true for all IE languages. Look at the English "however" -- is it a conjunction or an adverb? It's why grammarians started calling them "[conjunctive adverbs](https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/grammarpunct/conjadv/)."

With *quapropter*, the mechanism is clear, so this isn't the best example. It's originally a prepositional phrase with the "preposition" coming in second position (cf. what happened with *causa*). In Terence, you still see the full phrase ("qua me propter adduxi"), but it was well on its way to becoming a set phrase.

Comment: Thanks. Now i have to find out if this exexists in Portuguese